# Infinite limit of derivative

Tags: calculus, limits

Which of these statements is true? I was thinking that b is true but I am not entirely sure. Would the epsilon-delta be the best way to prove/disprove those statements?

a) Let $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and assume f is continuous at a and differentiable near a, except maybe at a.

If  $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f'(x) = \infty $, then $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} 
\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} = \infty $

b)If $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} 
\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} = \infty $, then $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f'(x) = \infty $

Comment: The abbreviation 'cts' is not standard, and the internet is big enough to hold full words. What have you tried to resolve this question?

Comment: Big hint: The mean value theorem.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I tried to use delta-epsilon but it didn't seem as a right way.